# Interpolate between each row of a data.frame

Tags: r, interpolation

I am looking to resample and interpolate between each row of a `data.frame` in a fast way. I don't mind working with `data.table` or other data structures if necessary. Here is a reproducible example :

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 2, 10),
                 y = c(10, 12, 0))
```

Desired output : a function `f(df, n)`, where `n` is the number of interpolation values that would lead to :

```
df_int <- f(df, 1)

# That would produce :
# df_int <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 2, 6, 10),
#                      y = c(10, 11, 12, 6, 0))

df_int <- f(df, 3)

# That would produce :
# df_int <- data.frame(x = c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
#                      y = c(10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 9, 6, 3, 0))
```

Some solutions were proposed using `approx` but that doesn't work in my case.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the role of `n` as "the number of interpolation values". Are these the number of interpolated values between any two given number x_i and x_{i+1}?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without consideration of speed

```
interpolate_vector <- function(x, n) {
  Reduce(function(x, tail_x) {
    c(head(x, -1), seq(tail(x, 1), tail_x[1], length.out = n + 2))
  }, init = x[1], x = tail(x, -1))
}

f <- function(df, n) {
  as.data.frame(lapply(df, interpolate_vector, n))
}
```

```
f(df, 1)
```

```
   x  y
1  0 10
2  1 11
3  2 12
4  6  6
5 10  0
```

```
f(df, 3)
```

```
     x    y
1  0.0 10.0
2  0.5 10.5
3  1.0 11.0
4  1.5 11.5
5  2.0 12.0
6  4.0  9.0
7  6.0  6.0
8  8.0  3.0
9 10.0  0.0
```

---

Without `Reduce` and growing vectors:

```
interpolate_vector_2 <- function(x, n) {
  res <- numeric(length = (length(x)-1) * (n+1) + 1)
  for (i in head(seq_along(x), -1)) {
    res[(i + (i-1)*n) : (i + i*n + 1)] <- 
      seq(x[i], x[i+1], length.out = n+2)
  }
  res
}

f_2 <- function(df, n) {
  as.data.frame(lapply(df, interpolate_vector_2, n))
}
```

---

Benchmark template (including @Maël's answers):

```r
res <- bench::press(
  rows = c(1e2, 1e3),
  n = c(1, 3, 10),
  {
    df <- data.frame(
      x = runif(rows),
      y = runif(rows)
    )
    bench::mark(
      zoo = f_3(df, n),
      loop = f_2(df, n),
      reduce = f(df, n),
      approx = f_4(df, n)
    )
  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: I added  another solution in the benchmark, hope it's okay!

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility with `zoo::na.approx`. The idea is to create a vector with `n` NA between the elements of the vectors, and then use `na.approx`. This solution is supposedly the fastest (see [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74065931/13460602)).

```r
library(zoo)
interp <- function(v, n){
  na_vec <- c(sapply(v, \(x) c(x, rep(NA, n))))[1:((length(v) - 1) * (n + 1) + 1)]
  zoo::na.approx(na_vec)
}

f <- function(df, n) as.data.frame(lapply(df, interp, n))
```

examples

```r
f(df, 1)
#    x  y
# 1  0 10
# 2  1 11
# 3  2 12
# 4  6  6
# 5 10  0

f(df, 3)
#      x    y
# 1  0.0 10.0
# 2  0.5 10.5
# 3  1.0 11.0
# 4  1.5 11.5
# 5  2.0 12.0
# 6  4.0  9.0
# 7  6.0  6.0
# 8  8.0  3.0
# 9 10.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `approx`:

```r
interp <- function(x, n){
  v = c()
  for(i in seq(length(x) - 1)) {
    tmp = approx(c(x[i], x[i + 1]), n = 2 + n)$y
    v = c(v, tmp)
  }
  v[!duplicated(v)]
}

f <- function(df, n) as.data.frame(lapply(df, interp, n))
```

examples

```r
f(df, 1)
#    x  y
# 1  0 10
# 2  1 11
# 3  2 12
# 4  6  6
# 5 10  0

f(df, 3)
#      x    y
# 1  0.0 10.0
# 2  0.5 10.5
# 3  1.0 11.0
# 4  1.5 11.5
# 5  2.0 12.0
# 6  4.0  9.0
# 7  6.0  6.0
# 8  8.0  3.0
# 9 10.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a another option using `approx`

```
f_5 <- function(df, n) {
  
  if (identical(n, 0)) {
    return(df)
  }
  
  lgt <- nrow(df)
  mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = lgt - 1)
  idx <- seq_len((lgt - 1) * (n + 1) + 1)

  out <- lapply(df, function(i) {
    tmp <- rbind(i[-lgt], mat)
    approx(c(tmp, i[lgt]), xout = idx)[["y"]]
    }
  )
  as.data.frame(out)
}
```

Example

```
f_5(df, n = 3)
#     x    y
#1  0.0 10.0
#2  0.5 10.5
#3  1.0 11.0
#4  1.5 11.5
#5  2.0 12.0
#6  4.0  9.0
#7  6.0  6.0
#8  8.0  3.0
#9 10.0  0.0
```

Benchmark against [Maël's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74067450/8583393)

```
res <- bench::press(
  rows = c(1e3, 1e4),
  n = c(1, 3, 10),
  {
    df <- data.frame(
      x = runif(rows),
      y = runif(rows)
    )
    bench::mark(
      zoo = f_3(df, n),
      approx2 = f_5(df, n)
    )
  }
)
plot(res) +
  ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]